# How to resolve lazy loading issue in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

The problem arose with lazy loading. In the essence of the task there is a field called "resultImage". This field contains a large picture and when unloading all task objects, I don’t want to unload it. The error occurs when the mapper converts the Task object into a DTO object.

Error logs;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU8sf.png)

Task entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TASKS", schema = "main")
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "RESULT_IMAGE_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Image resultImage;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PREVIEW_RESULT_IMAGE_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Image previewResultImage;
}
```

Image entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "IMAGES",schema = "main")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Image {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "DATA")
    @Lob
    private byte[] data;

}
```

DTO-class:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class ResponseDTO {

    private Long taskId;

    private String sampleImageData;

    private String imagePreviewResultData;
}
```

the method where the error occurs:

```
public List<ResponseDTO> getAllTasks(Long userId) {

        List<Task> tasks = taskRepository.findAllByUserId(userId);

        return tasks.stream().
                map(Mapper.INSTANCE::taskToResponseDTO).
                collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

transform method in mapper:

```
@org.mapstruct.Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface Mapper {

    Mapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(Mapper.class);

    @Mapping(target = "taskId", source = "id")
    @Mapping(target = "sampleImageData", source = "imageMetadata.sampleImage.data",qualifiedByName = "dataToBase64")
    @Mapping(target = "imagePreviewResultData", source = "previewResultImage.data",qualifiedByName = "dataToBase64")
    ResponseDTO taskToResponseDTO(Task task);
}
```

I tried to disable the mapping of fields that are not configured, but it did not help.

I will be glad for any help!

Comment: Please share error logs in the format of plain text

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after reviewing your Exception trace (which you should have added as text)

The problem is that the Jackson serialization library does not know how to handle Hibernate proxies (which are being used in case of lazy loading)

So you need to follow the advice which was present in the error log:

disable the feature `FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS` from the Jackson serialization configuration.